# Shuffle data frame rows depending on a factor

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame, for example:

```
letter class value
     A     0    55
     B     1    23
     C     1    12
     D     1     9
     E     2    68
     F     2    78
     G     2   187
```

I want to re-sample randomly the rows in each class to associate a `letter` to a new random `value` (but from the same class).

Desired example output:

```
letter class value
     A     0    55
     B     1    12
     C     1     9
     D     1    23
     E     2   187
     F     2    78
     G     2    68
```

I tried something with `dplyr` like:

`tab %>% group_by(class) %>% sample_n(size=3)`

But this sample 3 rows per group and I don't have the same number of values per group.

The only solution I found at the moment is to create `n` data frames for each class, and to shuffle each data frame independently. But as my class number is large, it might be too long and dirty.

Comment: Try `df1 %>% group_by(class) %>% mutate(value = value[sample(row_number())])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sample` on the sequence of rows (`row_number()`) and rearrange the 'value' based on the sampled index

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(class) %>% 
  mutate(value = value[sample(row_number())])
```

Or as @RonakShah mentioned in the comments, if we have only a single row, then using `sample` would trigger `sample` of the sequence of values.  So, if we directly use `sample` on the 'value', then an `if/else` condition can be used

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(class) %>%
  mutate(value = if(n() == 1) value else sample(value, n()))
```

---

If we want to use `sample_n`, it can be done within `do`

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(class) %>%
   do(sample_n(., size = nrow(.)))
```

NOTE: We need to specify `nrow` instead of `n()` as some of the tidyverse specific functions work within certain functions such as `mutate/fsummarise/filter/arrange` etc, but it is not implemented to work along with `sample_n`

Comment: @RonakShah Isnt it `55` in the expected output

Comment: yes, it is but when there is only single number in `sample` it works as `sample(1:55, 1)`

Comment: Okay, I was checking my previous solution in the comments. Thanks