# Shuffle rows in a dataframe based on a condition using R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, shuffle

I'm trying to shuffle all rows in a data frame based on a condition using R.

This is an example of my data frame:

```
l <- c("Ana", "Maria", "Hanne", "Liam","Sarah","Ella")
c <- c(1,1,2,3,3,2)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(l,c))
colnames(df) <- c("Name", "ClassNr")
```

What I aimed is to shuffle all rows making sure that each sequence of 3 rows has names from different ClassNr.
I have tried the following:

```
set.seed(55)
df[sample(nrow(df), 3),]
```

This code gives me 3 random rows but I need to add the condition of not having a given ClassNr repeated in each "block" of 3 rows. Also I need to repeat this once again to have the full list of names included in the "random data frame".

As example of the output would be:

```
  Name ClassNr
1 Ana        1
2 Ella       2
3 Liam       3
4 Maria      1
5 Hanne      2
6 Sarah      3
```

What is the best approach to solve this?

I have tried to use this example but I didn't manage to understand the solution in order to apply to my problem:
[Shuffle data frame rows depending on a factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255335/shuffle-data-frame-rows-depending-on-a-factor)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```r
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  split(f = as.factor(.$ClassNr)) %>% 
  map_dfr(~sample(.x$Name)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(),
               names_to = "ClassNr",
               values_to = "Name")
```

returning (for example)

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  ClassNr Name
  <chr>   <chr>
1 1       Ana  
2 2       Ella 
3 3       Sarah
4 1       Maria
5 2       Hanne
6 3       Liam
```

- We first split the data into groups based on the ClassNr. That's the `split`-part. Now we have three lists (one list for every class).
- Next we take every list and sample the elements, which is basically shuffling each list independently and bind the result together as dataframe.
- Finally we bring this dataframe into a long format.

Note: This approach will most likely fail if there are different numbers of names in each class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. Can you please explain the rational used in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply shuffle your names and then append the sequence of 1:3 two times? But I actually don't fully understand what you want to achieve, so maybe you can be a bit more clear.

(Note: I ordered the names alphabetically here for illustration, but this doesn't make sense in real life, because it would always lead to the same result)

```
set.seed(1)
Name <- sort(sample(l, 6, replace = FALSE))
ClassNr <- rep(1:3, 2)

shuffled_df <- data.frame(Name, ClassNr)

shuffled_df

            Name   ClassNr
1            Ana         1
2           Ella         2
3          Hanne         3
4           Liam         1
5          Maria         2
6          Sarah         3
```

Comment: I can not shuffle the names and append the sequence of 1:3 as this will mismatch the name as the ClassNr (for example Liam is part of ClassNr 3). With this example, I've tried to replicate what my real problem is: I have a list of 53 associates  with their full name (represented as Name) with the information to which department they belong to (represented as ClassNr). I need to shuffle all names in order to create a new list in which sequence of 3 rows I do not have associates from the same department (in my example from the same ClassNr) including all associates. Is this clear?

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather straightforward approach, but probably not the shortest.

```
library(dplyr)

l <- c("Ana", "Maria", "Hanne", "Liam","Sarah","Ella")
c <- c(1,1,2,3,3,2)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(l,c))
colnames(df) <- c("Name", "ClassNr")
```

Creating a list of 3 dataframes - one for each class. Rows are shuffled at this point in each of the 3 dataframes. `index` column is added for further sorting:

```
lst = list()

for (i in unique(df$ClassNr)) {  
  dat <- df %>% 
    filter(ClassNr == i)
  
  rows <- sample(nrow(dat))
  dat <- dat[rows, ] 
  dat <- dat %>% mutate(index = row_number())
  
  lst[[i]] = dat
}
```

Joining the 3 shuffled dataframes into the final `output` dataframe. Arranging by `index` and `ClassNr`:

```
output <- data.frame()

for (i in seq(1:length(lst))) {
  output <- output %>% rbind(lst[[i]])
}

output <- output %>%
  arrange(index, ClassNr) %>%
  select(-index)
```

Arranging by `index` ensures the 1-2-3 sequence. You can think of it like this: Taking first row from df with Class 1, adding first row of df with Class 2, then first row of Class 3. Then adding the second row from first, second and third datasets, etc.

Resulting in this:

```
    Name ClassNr
2  Maria       1
21  Ella       2
22  Liam       3
1    Ana       1
11 Hanne       2
12 Sarah       3
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would use *dplyr*'s `arrange()` to arrange ClassNr and then to arrange on a repeating number sequence:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(ClassNr) %>% 
  arrange(rep(1:(ceiling(nrow(df)/3)), 3)[1:nrow(df)]) 

   Name ClassNr
1   Ana       1
2 Hanne       2
3  Liam       3
4 Maria       1
5  Ella       2
6 Sarah       3
```

A little manipulation of the ordering sequence is needed, in case the number of rows isn't divisible by 3. e.g:

```
    Name ClassNr
1    Ana       1
2  Hanne       2
3   Liam       3
4  Maria       1
5   Ella       2
6  Sarah       3
7  Other       1
8 Other2       2
```

Comment: Really nice solution! I will use it. thanks!